# how to call js file according to media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to call js file according to media query, like css media query condition

till now I have tried

```
<script>
  if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 1224px)')){
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="pistachioz_js/jquery.fullPage.js">      </script>');
</script>
```

but is not working for me...

Comment: you may want to try `window.innerHeight` & `window.innerWidth`. by the way you missed closing curly brace

Comment: Your script will still be active after a resize. It should watch for `.matchMedia` each time it's going to do something

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a javascript plugin (no jquery needed) called **enquire.js**

> enquire.js allows you to harness media queries in JavaScript, giving
>   you the tools to create advanced responsive sites.

http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

have fun!